# Set MongoDB OpLog to ignore a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

Our workflow includes a collection used for caching, with intensive WR ops that hammers the OpLog window across the whole cluster.

Is it possible to tell the OpLog to ignore this collection?

NOTE: Being a cache collection for a backend service, the content is not important for recovery/backup purposes and can be dropped anytime.

EDIT: probably the answer is 'no' because the oplog is used to sync the replicaset nodes, hence nodes won't be synced unless either:

- W ops write to all nodes at once (unsafe?) or
- the collection is set up only on one node (not possible?).

Comment: Maybe deploy an In-Memory MongoDB for temporary data?

Comment: The backend svc is on AWS ECS Fargate and scales horizontally. IIUC each container should have a mongod process. Alternatively, an additional tasks shared across all (or a subset of) containers?

Answer (score 0):

With all the caveats imaginable and with caution, you could consider the [local database](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/local-database/) which doesn't replicate nor log.

Comment: What if such behaviour may be configurable for any database? I couldn't find such a thing, tho: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1559

Comment: From the discussion in that ticket it appears that what you are looking for is not a current feature. I provided a mechanism to accomplish your task with the current version of the database. For existing collections you can `renameCollection` to the local database or use `mongo-tools` to copy the collection. Again, being careful to understand the limits of the `local` database and having backups prior to this if needed.